# Fisher puzzle with 4 fishers

Tags: puzzle

Four people went fishing one day. They put all the fish in one basket. Then they left for a rest. When the first person came back, they divided the fish into four equal parts with one fish left over. They threw away that one, and left with their ration. When the second person was back, assuming that they were the first one coming back, they divided the remaining fish into four equal parts of one fish left over. They threw away that one, and left with their ration. When the third person was back, assuming that they were the first one back, they did the same thing as the first two. When the fourth person was back, assuming that they were the first one back, they did the same thing as the first three.
What is the minimal number of fish they caught in total?
For reference :

There is a known solution to that question with 3 fishermans, here it is :
Let a
be the number of fish. Then you know that a=3b+1
for some non-negative integer b
since Fisherman1 saw that the remainder was one when he tried to divide the fish into thirds. He threw one back and took b
or himself, leaving 2b
. Similarly, 2b=3c+1
and 2c=3d+1
, where d
is the number of fish the third fisherman ended up taking at the end.
We know that d
must be odd, so equal to 2k+1
for some non-negative k
. Plugging that in we get
2c=6k+4
or
c=3k+2.
Therefore
2b=9k+7
and k
must also be odd, k=2l+1
. Then
2b=18l+16
or
b=9l+8
and
a=27l+25.
25 is the The smallest value of a, occurs when l=0
The 1st fisherman sees 25 fish, tosses one back, and takes 8 (leaving 16). the 2nd fisherman tosses another back, taking five and leaving 10. Lastly the 3rd tosses one and takes three.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: What is the minimal number of fish they caught in total?

Comment: Then the answer is 11

Comment: The answer is 253
(253-1)/4 = 63 and the rest is 189
(189-1)/4 = 47 and the rest is 141
(141-1)/4 = 35 and the rest is 105
(105-1)/4 = 26 and the rest is 78

Comment: ok you can post it as an answer and accept your own answer than

Comment: I need the proof - here is the proof for the 3 fihermans variation : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495646/math-puzzle-fishing

Comment: What is your question ? I mean post a question not the copy of your problem.

Comment: Welcome to SE, take a look around at some questions and answers to get a sense of how well-posed questions go and how they look. Many times, new users just ask a question expect answer and do not provide context or show what they have tried.

Comment: The question is that there is a full solution for the 3 fishermans variation , what is the full solution for 4 fishermans variation ?
I tried to follow the logic by replacing d with a number that can be divided by 3 , just like they did in the referred post by replacing d withan  odd number like this : 2k+1

Comment: What is d ? Come on, Edit your post.

Comment: I have edited my post, I hope that it is now clearer.

Comment: The answer is still 11. Please enclose maths with dollar sign. Did you check other well recieved questions on this forum ?

Answer (score 1):

Now the most important thing to remember in such type of question is that for any step of this procedure, the number of fishes taken away and left, both should be natural number (which is quite obvious).

So, let's start with the story.
Let the initial number of fishes in the bucket be $n + 1$.
*I've taken total of fishes to be n + 1 rather than just n because it will be easier remove 1 fish without worrying much about the complexity while we build our expression.*

So, we get: $$n + 1 = \frac{3n}{4} + \frac{n}{4} + 1$$
Here, $n + 1$ is the initial number of fishes in the bucket.
$\frac{3n}{4}$ is the number of fishes left after the first fisherman took his cut.
$\frac{n}{4}$ is the number of fishes the first fisherman took as his cut.
$1$ is the number of fish that he threw away.

Now, when the second fisherman arrived at the scene, the basket had only $\frac{3n}{4}$ fishes left, let's take it as another variable, $m + 1$.
$\therefore m + 1 = \frac{3n}{4}$
So, we get, $$m + 1 = \frac{3m}{4} + \frac{m}{4} + 1$$
The second fisherman keeps $\frac{m}{4}$ fishes, throws away $1$ fish and leaves $\frac{3m}{4}$ fishes.

Now when the third fisherman arrives, only $\frac{3m}{4}$ fishes were left in the basket, let's again take it in another variable, $p + 1$.
$\therefore p + 1 = \frac{3m}{4}$
So, we get,
$$p + 1 = \frac{3p}{4} + \frac{p}{4} + 1$$
The third fisherman keeps $\frac{p}{4}$ fishes, throws away $1$ fish and leaves $\frac{3p}{4}$ fishes.

For the last fisherman, only $\frac{3p}{4}$ fishes were there, let's call it $q + 1$.
$\therefore q + 1 = \frac{3p}{4}$
So, we get,
$$q + 1 = \frac{3q}{4} + \frac{q}{4} + 1$$
The fourth fisherman keeps $\frac{q}{4}$ fishes, throws away $1$ fish and leaves $\frac{3q}{4}$ fishes.

The last thing we need to consider is that even the number of fishes left in the basket should be a natural number as well. So, let call it $l$.
$\therefore l = \frac{3q}{4}$

Now, going back from where we had started, the initial number of fishes were $n + 1$. Let's open up the variables from top to bottom.
$\to n + 1$ 
$\to \frac{4}{3}(m + 1) + 1 \{\because m + 1 = \frac{3n}{4}\}$
$\to \frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}(p + 1) + 1\right) + 1 \{\because p + 1 = \frac{3m}{4}\}$
$\to \frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}(q + 1) + 1\right) + 1\right) + 1 \{\because p + 1 = \frac{3q}{4}\}$
$\to \frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4l}{3} + 1\right) + 1\right) + 1\right) + 1 \{\because q = \frac{3l}{4}\}$

And in the end we have, initial number of fishes are:
$$n + 1 = \frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4l}{3} + 1\right) + 1\right) + 1\right) + 1$$

Let's get it simplified a bit, you'll get:
$$n + 1 = \frac{256l + 525}{81}$$

Now for minimum value of $l \in N$ such that $n + 1 \in N$, since we need both the initial number of fishes in the basket and the remaining number of fishes in the bucket to be Natural Numbers. We basically need the term $\frac{256l + 525}{81}$ to be a natural number for the minimum possible value of $l$.

You can either take the long way to solve it (trust me its waste of hours), use some [clever mathematical ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117235/find-the-least-number-which-when-divided-by-2-3-4-5-6-leaves-a-remainder-of#:%7E:text=You%20definitely%20need%20n%20%E2%89%A1%201%20%28mod%2060%29,positive%20number%20is%20420%20%E2%88%92%20119%20%3D%20301.) to solve it. I'm gonna automate it instead using Python.

```
for l in range(1, 81 + 1):
    if (256*l + 525) % 81 == 0: print(i)
```

Output:
`>>78`

In case you're not quite familiar with Python or programming, the above code loops the values of $l$ from $1$ to $81$, and for each case, checks if the remainder comes $0$ on dividing with $81$, and prints out the value of $l$ in case the situation is satisfied. And we chose the range $1$ to $81$ because we know that for every odd number $n$ (except $5$), it will give remainder $r (r < n, r \in N)$ at least once for the range span of $1$ to $n$.

The code gave out $78$ as the answer. Now, substitute the value:
$$n + 1 = \frac{256\times78 + 525}{81}$$
$$n + 1 = 253$$

**Remember that we took the initial number of fishes in the basket to be $n + 1$ and not $n$.**
Hence, you get the minimum value of fishes in the basket to be $253$.

**Edit:** If you want to repeat this thing for $n^{th}$ times (here $n$ was 4), You can write the total number of fishes to be:
$$f(f(f(..._\text{n times}...f(l)...)))$$
Where,
$$f(x) = \frac{b}{a}x + r$$
where, 
$\frac{a}{b}$ is the fraction of fishes left after each step (here, it is $\frac{3}{4}$)
$r$ is the number of fishes thrown away or the remainder. (here, it is $1$)
For this case, we have:
$$f(x) = \frac{4}{3}x + 1$$

On simplification, the general term becomes:
$$\text{(Total number of fishes)} = \frac{b^{n}l + \sum\limits_{i=1}^nra^ib^{n - i}}{a^n}$$
The minimum value of $l$ for this term to become a whole number can be calculated using the below python script:

```
# Define the variables
a = 3 # numerator of fraction of fishes taken away by each fishermen
b = 4 # denominator of fraction of fishes taken away by each fishermen
n = 4 # number of fishermen
r = 1 # number of fishes thrown away by each fishermen (or the remainder)

# Define the functions that calculate the minimum number of fishes left in the bucket at last
def minFishesLeft(a, b, n, r):
    for l in range(1, a**n + 1):
        if ((b**n)*l + sum(r*(a**i)*b**(n-i) for i in range(1, n + 1))) % a**n == 0: return l
    raise Exception # Raise an error when the above condition isn't satisfied within the above range

# Print out the initial number of fishes
print(((b**n)*minFishesLeft(a, b, n, r) + sum(r*(a**i)*b**(n-i) for i in range(1, n + 1)))/a**n)
```

Or in case of smaller fractions and remainders, you can calculate the minimum number of fishes left after the story manually as well, but you'll need the algorithm or some other way for larger values.

Hope this helps.